# Как добавить Get параметр к строке в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача следующая. Мне нужно добавить гет параметры в зависимости от указанной строки. К примеру:

```
domain.com
```

что бы добавить гет параметр необходимо поставить "/" в конце строки и тогда склеивать с гет параметрами.

Но если пользователь указал ссылку вида:

```
domain.com/index.php
```

то сами понимаете сразу можно клеить без "/".

Если пользователь указал

```
domain.com/rise
```

то тогда будет domain.com/rise?get

Если

```
domain.com/rise/
```

то

```
domain.com/rise/?get
```

Помогите пожалуйста определить этот момент

Comment: Думаю, вам нужен оператор "+"

Comment: попробуйте так var uri = window.location + "?"+'getParam=xyz'

Comment: плохо думаете. мне нужно определить когда ставить слеш а когда нет. то что добавлять + итак понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то будет как-то так. Слеш добавится только если url не заканчивается на `.php` или слеш.

```js
function serializeGet(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}

function addGet(url, get) {

  if (typeof(get) === 'object') {
      get = serializeGet(get);
  }

  if (url.match(/\?/)) {
      return url + '&' + get;
  }

  if (!url.match(/\.\w{3,4}$/) && url.substr(-1, 1) !== '/') {
    url += '/';
  }
  
  return url + '?' + get;
}

console.log(addGet('ya.ru', 'a=b'));

console.log(addGet('ya.ru/', 'a=b'));

console.log(addGet('ya.ru/index.php', 'a=b'));

console.log(addGet('ya.ru/index.php?text=12345', 'a=b'));

console.log(addGet('ya.ru/index.php?text=12345', {a:"100%", b:"abc", d:128}));
```

Comment: А что если я добавлю  console.log(addGet('ya.ru?xyz=trulyalya', 'a=b'));
Поправьте функционал и для этих случаев тогда будет норм .Ато это неполноценный код.и получается что так короче и оптимально var uri = window.location + "?"+'getParam=xyz'

Comment: А есть какие-то функции что бы определить расширение страницы? вдруг там html, php, aspx, и прочее. Хочется универсализировать функцию

Comment: Можно регуляркой определять по паттерну `\.\w{3,4}$`

Comment: точно, протупил! это решит вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ. @iSeeDev

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan А где в вопросе такая задача? Задача добавить get к url без get. Но я добавлю в ответ

Comment: @ilyaplot Но и не отрицается же. Вы когда пишете код должны написать его максимально оптимальным ,и предугадать ошибки в дальнейшем.Ведь заказчики могут и не догадаться об этом

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Ну не фреймворк же сразу писать :) Обновил ответ, вроде бы работает хорошо.

Comment: @ilyaplot Вот это по человечески.Написал код и пошел спокойно спать :)

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Что-то я разошелся и добавил возможность представления get как объекта :)

Comment: @ilyaplot Искренни Вам благодарен! Функция универсальная! задача решена!)

Comment: @ilyaplot Так можно и фреймворк написать :). Ну я думаю достаточно. Исчерпывающий ответ. Браво